# Verilog apply force to module output without changing internal state

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, register-transfer-level, digital-design

In my testbench, I want to simulate a system condition by forcing a certain module's output in the RTL:

```
force DUT.driving_module.xx = 0;
```

But when doing this with the *force* command, the wire that drives the output inside the module is also forced, which leads to other parts of the system being also affected.
What I really need is to force the output of the module, without changing its internal state, like this:

[image]

I can't modify the RTL code at all. Is there a way to achieve this from the testbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a port with a wire on both sides of the port connection, the wire gets collapsed into a single wire.

The way to do this is use `logic` instead of `wire` inside your module. The only place you should be using `wire` anywhere in SystemVerilog is if the signal has multiple drivers.

In Verilog, you can always make the output port of a module a `reg`

In either case, an output port that is a variable creates an implicit continuous assignment to whatever it connected to in the higher level module. Continuous assignments are uni-directional and a force will not propagate back into the module.

Comment: In some simulators, if you add debug flags to your simulation build, it will not do the logical wire collapse.  This works in VCS, afaik, and I think ncsim, or whatever Cadence is calling it this week.  Then you can do a `force` or a `put` on the wire and it will only effect "downstream" wire.  Not realistic modeling at all, but useful.

Comment: @dave_59 things in fact are a bit more complex. For simplicity's sake I didn't mention that my design is a netlist composed of primitives (mantaining the hierarchy of the original RTL design). So, the wires and its drivers are all defined by the synthesis tool. That's what I meant by "can't modify the code"

Comment: Why is that you can ask a tool to modify the code for you, but you can't do it yourself? Of course you can modify the code, it's just a text file.

Comment: Well, of course I can just go ahead and modify the netlist, but it wouldn't be very neat - it's almost never a good idea to manually modify auto-generated code, if the design is re-compiled you have to do it again, no documentation, etc...

Comment: I guess it depends on the original intent in using a `force` statement. If you are using it to debug an unknown problem, or to verify a potential fix, then the force is a temporary statement anyways. If you are doing this to _fast_ initialize a block of code, there might be other tool specific alternatives.